# Oberbegriff für "bearbeiten", "neu" und "löschen"?

Tags: synonym

Gibt es einen Oberbegriff für die Wörter "bearbeiten", "neu", "löschen" und evtl. noch "anzeigen"?

Hintergrund ist folgender: Ich arbeite zurzeit an einem WebService, das für diese Dinge nur einen Controller (also einen Aufruf) benötigt. Das heißt, es wird zum Beispiel ein Link:
webseite.at/person/{Oberbegriff} aufgerufen, mit dem die Person eben angezeigt, bearbeitet, oder gelöscht werden kann.
webseite.at/person/bearbeiten passt mir nicht wirklich, weil es keinen Hinweis darauf gibt, dass auch neue Personen angelegt und Personen gelöscht werden können.

Mit Suchmaschinen habe ich nichts gefunden (auch kein englisches Wort).

Comment: Deutsch: verwalten. Als Anglizismus: administrieren (da im Englischen immer: "administrate", wobei administrate = create+edit+delete die Standardverwendung ist).

Comment: Im Englischen werden solche Operationen auch als CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) bezeichnet. Das ist aber nicht so eingängig, daher wären `vorgang`, `operation` oder `verwalten` denkbar. Aus REST-Sicht ist es übrigens nicht so schön, wenn Du das so entwirfst - hier sollte jeder Vorgang ein eigener Request sein (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT).

Comment: Hallo Thorsten,
ich verwende ja für jeden Vorgang ein eigenes Request, aber nur einen Controller. d.h. die Request gehen an folgende Adressen:
GET webseite.at/person/verwalten/id zum anzeigen
POST webseite.at/person/verwalten für neu
POST webseite.at/person/verwalten/id zum bearbeiten und
DELETE webseite.at/person/verwalten/id zum löschen

Comment: Was wäre mit "Person" selbst?

Comment: Hallo user unknown ,
das wäre natürlich die schönste Lösung, aber ist programmiertechnisch leider nicht möglich..

Answer (score 4):

Mein Vorschlag wäre:

> webseite/person/Aktionen

Answer (score 0):

Ich musste an "Aktion(en)" und "Interaktion" denken. Am besten ware natuerlich "Rechtsklick" :p

Comment: "Rechtsklick" ist nicht möglich, es handelt sich ja um ein WebService, d. h. man sendet eine Anfrage mit einem Browser oder ähnlichem ;)

Comment: Ist mir schon klar :D

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es mit **"Verwalten"** (oder engl. *"manage"*) als Oberbegriff für "bearbeiten", "neu", "löschen" und evtl. "anzeigen"?

"Verwalten" ist generell genug um ggf. später weitere Operationen hinzuzufügen.

In Ihrem Beispiel wäre die URL des Webservices:

```
webseite.at/person/verwalten
```

Die genannten Operationen passen auch zum Begriff [**"CRUD"** (engl. create, read, update, delete)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD), das wäre eine weitere Möglichkeit:

```
webseite.at/person/crud
```